# What is the best UX for collecting a user's height in metric rather than imperial?

Tags: interaction-design, design-patterns

In Imperial, we normally collect feet and inches in separate fields, often via dropdown. In metric, what's the standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically it's just a single input box, rather than split into two for feet and inches.

[image] [image]

Comment: Are centimeters the best unit to ask for, or another unit (such as meters)?

Comment: Definitely centimeters are the best, that's the standard. Meters are too big units to ask for, and decimeters are too uncommon.

Answer (score 2):

Collect in centimeters. It requires one input field for the user (so there's improved efficiency) and centimeters are more commonly referred to when talking about a person's height (so it's more relatable to the user). For example, Wikipedia use centimeters to refer to height as shown in the link to an AFL players bio (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nic_Naitanui) which refers to their height in centimeters.

Answer (score 1):

On which to use - This depends on your target market.  A bit of user research will reveal some pretty good indicators.  For example Doctors might use a different kind of measurement than a teacher or a student etc.  The answers are in user research.

Good luck

m